# Full-Text Index Comparisons in SQL Server 2005 Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, full-text-search

How does one compare the text field of one record to all the other records in SQL server to return, for example, the top 5 most related records?

An example of the functionality I'm after are the various Related Posts plugins for Wordpress that produce a list of links to posts related to the post currently being viewed.

Cheers,
Iain

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for these responses.  I'm familiar with the referenced functions, but I'm not sure they do what I need.  For example:

```
SELECT P.id, 'Product' AS Type, FT.rank, C.url + '/' + P.url AS url, longTitle, shortTitle, P.description
FROM Products P
     INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE (Products, (longTitle, shortTitle), '"my text content"') AS FT ON P.id = FT.[key]
     LEFT JOIN Product_Categories PC ON P.id = PC.productID
     LEFT Join Categories C ON C.id = PC.categoryID
WHERE [primary] = 1
ORDER BY rank DESC
```

returns only rows with the exact phrase "my text content" - I need rows with only "text" to be returned, but at a lower rank.  If I change the query as follows:

```
SELECT P.id, 'Product' AS Type, FT.rank, C.url + '/' + P.url AS url, longTitle, shortTitle, P.description
FROM Products P
     INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE (Products, (longTitle, shortTitle), '"my" or "text" or "content"') AS FT ON P.id = FT.[key]
     LEFT JOIN Product_Categories PC ON P.id = PC.productID
     LEFT Join Categories C ON C.id = PC.categoryID
WHERE [primary] = 1
ORDER BY rank DESC
```

I get more rows, but rows with all three words don't appear to rank clearly higher than rows with 1 of the words.

Any further thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, from the excellent Robert Cain:

http://arcanecode.com/2007/06/28/getting-started-with-sql-server-2005-full-text-searching-part-3-%E2%80%93-using-sql/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CONTAINSTABLE , this returns a RANK column you can use to sort by.

```
SELECT TOP 5 [Key] FROM CONTAINSTABLE ([YourFullText],'SomethingToSearch')
ORDER BY [RANK] DESC
```